# Git pull request giving an SSL error

Tags: git, ssl

When I try running `git pull` I just recently started to see

fatal: unable to access 'https://username:token@github.com/MyRepo/tools/': Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.

I've been using Git on this machine for quite a while now without any issues.  This just started happening recently.  If I run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect github.com:443` the cert looks pretty normal to me.  Maybe the Amazon Linux instance I'm using doesn't trust Digicert any more? Anyone know how I can fix this?  As a workaround I've been using `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=false` but I'd prefer to fix it correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: Was your certificate created before June 1, 2016?  If so, many places mark that as un-trusted.  [Here](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3225508/web-browsers/google-squeezes-symantec-until-it-certs.html) is one example.

Comment: I'm using the default certificate which comes with Amazon Linux so I'm not sure.  How can I check that?

Comment: So far I've tried using the instructions here to get the github.com cert: [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/).  And then I used the instructions here to install it: [link](https://techjourney.net/update-add-ca-certificates-bundle-in-redhat-centos/).  I tried installing it to the /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ directory and directly to /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt.   Neither worked.  Using `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=true git pull` has been useful to see the location of the cert.